# Google maps animate particular marker on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this google map code below where I added bounce animation on 'click' to the markers but when I click on any marker only the first marker is animated instead of that particular marker.

I have tried a few answers but they don't seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>

    function initMap() {
        var locations = [
                  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
                  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
                  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
                  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
                  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
                ];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

        zoom: 8,
                    //custom map styling
        styles: [
                    {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#ececec'}]},
                    {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#000000'}]},
                    {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#000000'}]},
                    {
                        featureType: 'administrative.locality',
                        elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                        stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'poi',
                          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                          stylers: [{color: '#777777'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'poi.park',
                          elementType: 'geometry',
                          stylers: [{color: '#bebdbd'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'poi.park',
                          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                          stylers: [{color: '#a4a2a2'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'road',
                          elementType: 'geometry',
                          stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'road',
                          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                          stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'road',
                          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                          stylers: [{color: '#9ca5b3'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'road.highway',
                          elementType: 'geometry',
                          stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'road.highway',
                          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                          stylers: [{color: '#1f2835'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'road.highway',
                          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                          stylers: [{color: '#f3d19c'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'transit',
                          elementType: 'geometry',
                          stylers: [{color: '#999999'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'transit.station',
                          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                          stylers: [{color: '#777777'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'water',
                          elementType: 'geometry',
                          stylers: [{color: '#cccccc'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'water',
                          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                          stylers: [{color: '#e8e9ea'}]
                        },
                        {
                          featureType: 'water',
                          elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
                          stylers: [{color: '#cccccc'}]
                        },
                        {
                            featureType: 'landscape.natural',
                            elementType: 'geometry',
                            stylers: [{color: '#000000'}]
                         }

                      ],
                    //map positioning and type    
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    disableDefaultUI: true
                });
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                var marker, i;

                for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

                      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),

                        map: map,

                      });
                        //event listener for popup
                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                          infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                      })(marker, i));

                      //event listener for bounce animation
                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                              marker.setAnimation(null);
                            } else {
                              marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                            }
                          });

                }






      }




    </script> 
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAwQB2GuZ2oDC2tP2A_6XwlEraV2Cyku3E&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 event listeners setup for the marker click event.  I'm guessing the one that's opening your infowindow works fine.  Use the same approach with the 2nd one. Or even better, just have a single event listener that does both pieces of functionality.

```
marker.addListener('click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }

        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
})(marker, i));
```